# как сменить месторасположение tmp директории для war в wildfly

Tags: linux, upload, wildfly

Приветствую! имеется Wildfly 10 на линуксе. На нем задеплоена куча war & ear. Если юзер закачивает патч на сервер через одну из варок (например appName.war), то файл сначала кладется в /tmp/, потом деплоится в $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/appName.war/ а потом закачивается в папку постоянного хранения патчей, прописанную в коде appName.war. Проблема в том, что /opt/ достаточно сильно забита и при закачке патчей больших размеров места в /opt/ уже не хватает. Вопрос: как прописать использование для деплоя не $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/appName.war/, а другую папку? При этом, чтобы другие приложения разворачивались по-прежнему в $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/. Догадываюсь, что что-то надо прописать в web.xml варки. Но что конкретно?

Comment: [передача опций](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Command+line+parameters) не подходит?

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Нет, не подходит такое решение. Как я понял, можно поменять расположение tmp-директории для всех развернутых приложений. А это неприемлемо. Изменения не должны затрагивать работу других приложений. И нет доступа к редактированию команды запуска WF.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено.Либо указываем параметр в аннотации сервлета @MultipartConfig(location="/tmp"), либо прописываем тег в WEB-INF/web.xml в конфигурации сервлета

```
<multipart-config>
    <location>/tmp</location>    
</multipart-config>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/247413)

Comment: @Suvitruf, ответ уже обновили.

Comment: @Qwertiy замечательно ^_^